# How do I access a list of maps nesting in ${body} of Apache Camel in Java

Tags: java, json, apache, dictionary, apache-camel

I am trying to access data in the incoming {body} of my incoming Json I have done the unmarshaling with Jackson and mapped it to a Java Map with

```
  `.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, java.util.Map.class)
`
```

My Json data is something like this after unmarshal step above

```
`{ "projectId" : 12345,
"title" : “12345 - Plant 1 Processing",
"partners": [{"partnerName": "partnerJV1", "partnerLocation": "JA"},
{"partnerName": "partnerJV2", "partnerLocation": "FL"},
{"partnerName": "partnerJV3", "partnerLocation": "OH"}
]`
```

The last part can have 0-N number of partnerName, partnerLocation maps in the partners List.

Now I am having to insert this data into a SQL table with

```
            .to("sql:classpath:sql/sql_queries.sql")
```

My sql_queries.sql has the following query in it to insert data fields into the table:

```
`INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(PID, TITLE, PartnerName1, PartnerLocation1, PartnerName2, PartnerLocation2, PartnerName3, PartnerLocation3) VALUES(:#${body['projectId']}, :#${body['title']}, :#${body['partners[0]']['partnerName']}, :#${body['partners[0]']['partnerLocation']} )'
```

I cannot figure out the syntax for the last part which is a List of Maps. If it should be

```
`:#${body['partners[0]']['partnerName']}`
```

or something else in order for me to get that value.

Any hints would help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me in the end was this:

`:#${body['partners'][0]['partnerName']}`

but I would love to find a way to iterate over the values like a list in Java if I don't know the size of it to begin with.

Comment: EDIT: deleted my comment. I misunderstood the issue.